# How to assign the data bus with data more than the width in verilog

Tags: verilog, databus

I have a data bus of width `[127:0]` which is 128 bits.

I have data of `[4095:0]`   which is  32769 bits .

I want to send continuously this 4Kb data through data bus.

How can I do this?

Comment: You might need some signals indicating burst, its transfer length and size signals as in AXI.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? See [ask] and share a [mcve]!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just split up the data into 128 bits and send it. In case you need to do it ever clock you can always store it into a FIFO take a huge chunk of data. Split and send. Then take another chunk.